# C# Suspending Thread until Server responds

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await, resume, suspend

I am trying to make a function that when called returns back information to the caller that is on a server. What I want in this function, is that it creates a thread that issues the command to the server, and then suspends itself until the server responds back with the answer.

```
public AccountState GetAccount(string key)
{
  AccountState state = null;
  Thread t = new Thread(() =>
  {
    _connection.SomeCommandSentToServer(key);
    accountRequests.TryAdd(key, (Thread.CurrentThread, null));
    //Suspend current thread until ServerReponseHere is called
    Thread.CurrentThread.Suspend();
    //We have been resumed, value should be in accountRequests now
    accountRequests.TryRemove(key, out var item);
    state = item.AccountState;
  });
  t.Start();

  return state;
}


public ConcurrentDictionary<string, (Thread Thread, AccountState AccountState)> accountRequests = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, (Thread Thread, AccountState AccountState)>();

///Once server is done with processed command, call to this function made
public void ServerReponseHere(string key, AccountState state)
{
  accountRequests.TryGetValue(username, out var item);
  accountRequests.TryUpdate(username, (item.Thread, new AccountState()), item);
  item.Thread.Resume();
}
```

My Idea then is that in a different function, when server responds back, it calls the ResumeThread function shown above.

C# says that Suspend / Resume are deprecated functions however, -- what is a better way to do this?

---

### UPDATE

Clarification about "SomeCommandSentToServer" -- This just sends a command to the server via TCP sockets.

In that call, all that is really happening is a transmission to the server. I'm using a library that uses WinSock2.h call of "Send()"     -- Yes I know it is a deprecated library... but the library I'm using requires it.

I have a separate thread that polls input from the server.  So I have no way to "await" on this SomeCommandSentToServer -- I would need to await on some sort of call back function (aka the resume function I was mentioning)  -- to make this work.

I am unsure how to do that

Comment: Looks like async-await is your answer

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific on how to use Tasks to make it work?

Comment: How do you get your `AccountState`? `_connection.SomeCommand` doesn't seem to return anything.

Comment: As I said -- The SomeCommand -- issue a request to the server, and the server will then call ResumeThread() at some point ---

Comment: We don't know exactly when it will be returned... that is the whole point of the question

Comment: [async and await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/) were made exactly for this scenario.

Comment: Boilerplate is to never wait for a slow server.  But to run code when it tells you it is done.  Well supported in .NET with BeginXxxx() or XxxxAsync() or Task/async/await.  The snippet you posted is too opaque to tell you how to do it, seems you already wrapped it with a SomeCommandSentToServer() that isn't doing it right.

Comment: @IlanKeshet Could you provide the code for the SomeCommandSentToServer method?

Comment: @Kzrystof please read the Update shown above

Comment: @IlanKeshet Please read the updated answer ;) I hope this will help.

Comment: @Kzrystof thanks ill have a look, it looks good though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With all the information available from the question, here is what you should aim for when using the async / await pattern:

```
public async Task<AccountState> GetAccountAsync(string key)
{
    // The method SomeCommandSentToServerAsync must be changed to support async.
    AccountState state = await _connection.SomeCommandSentToServerAsync(key);

    return state;
}
```

It is highly unlikely that you need anything else. By that, I mean you will **not** have to manipulate threads directly, put them in a concurrent dictionary and manually suspend or resume them because it looks horrible from a maintenance perspective ;)

.NET will take care of the threading part, meaning the magic of the `async` infrastructure will most likely release the current thread (assuming a call is actually made to the server) until the server returns a response.

Then the infrastructure will either use the existing synchronization context -*if you are on a UI thread for instance*- or grab a thread from the thread pool -*if not*- to run the rest of the method.

You could even reduce the size of the method a bit more by simply returning a `Task` with a result of type `AccountState`:

```
public Task<AccountState> GetAccountAsync(string key)
{
    // The method SomeCommandSentToServerAsync must be changed to support async.
    return _connection.SomeCommandSentToServerAsync(key);
}
```

In both example, you will haver to make the callers `async` as well:

```
public async Task TheCallerAsync()
{
    // Grab the key from somewhere.
    string key = ...;

    var accountState = await <inst>.GetAccountAsync(key);

    //  Do something with the state.
    ...
}
```

**Turning a legacy method into an async method**

Now, regarding the legacy `SomeCommandSentToServer` method. There is a way to await that legacy method. Yes, you can turn that method into an asynchronous method that can be used with the `async` / `await`.

Of course, I do not have all the details of your implementation but I hope you will get the idea of what needs to be done. The magical class to do that is called [TaskCompletionSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcompletionsource-1?view=netframework-4.7.2).

What it allows you to do is to give you access to a `Task`. You create the instance of that `TaskCompletionSource` class, you keep it somewhere, you send the command and immediately return the Task property of that new instance.

Once you get the result from your polling thread, you grab the instance of `TaskCompletionSource`, get the `AccountState` and call `SetResult` with the account state. This will mark the task as completed and do the resume part you were asking for :)

Here is the idea:

```
    public Task<AccountState> SomeCommandSentToServerAsync(string key)
    {
        var taskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<AccountState>();

        //  Find a way to keep the task in some state somewhere
        //  so that you can get it the polling thread.

        //  Do the legacy WinSock Send() command.

        return taskCompletionSource.Task;
    }

    // This would be, I guess, your polling thread.
    // Again, I am sure it is not 100% accurate but 
    // it will hopefully give you an idea of where the key pieces must be.
    private void PollingThread()
    {
         while(must_still_poll)
         {
             //  Waits for some data to be available.

             //  Grabs the data.

             if(this_is_THE_response)
             {
                 // Get the response and built the account state somehow...

                 AccountState accountState = ...

                 // Key piece #1
                 // Grab the TaskCompletionSource instance somewhere.

                 // Key piece #2
                 // This is the magic line:
                 taskCompletionSource.SetResult(accountState);

                 // You can also do the following if something goes wrong:
                 // taskCompletionSource.SetException(new Exception());
             }
         }
    }
```

Comment: I don't think you understand that the SomeCommandSentToServer is a networked call --  there isn't a direct way for me inside that function to know when I need to wait, or when I know when I'm getting my value back

Comment: This SomeCommandSentToServer issues something on a different thread -- which then sends to the server that command,  -- then on a different thread which polls for server input gets the command, and then responds in the "ServerResponseHere"

Comment: Generally network calls are naturally asynchronous. You tell them what to do, and what code to run when they complete doing it. You often don't even need to use a thread to get this asynchrony to work. This is exactly a perfect async/await use case. However there's nowhere near enough info posted for people to help you. Also the "unlikely you need anything else" depends on the environment this is running in. It won't magically work, for example, from a console app. You shouldn't need to suspend/resume at all. Look for examples, this is such a common use of async/await.

Comment: @Flydog57 By the "unlikely you need anything else", I was meaning you do not have to manipulate threads and put them in a dictionnary :)

Comment: Worked like a charm! thanks very very much @Kzrystof

Comment: @IlanKeshet Awesome ;)